# How are fathiers raced?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, animals

In *The Last Jedi*, when Finn and Rose were sneaking around near the Canto Bight casino to find a codebreaker, they met a small pack of animals called fathiers.  Apparently these were used for some sort of racing event in a race track next to the casino.  But what kind of races exactly?

- Where the fathiers running around the track alone like in a greyhound race?
- Or did they have a rider person (jockey) sitting on top of them, like in a horse race?
- Or was the rider on a small carriage pulled by the fathier, like in carriage driving races?

Comment: Don't we see a rider on one in the movie?

Comment: @Allball103, yeah during the scene where they _show them racing_.  I don't get the question, honestly.  Unless the asker hasn't seen the movie or took a bathroom break during that scene

Comment: @Kevin I've seen the movie only once. There's no home media edition yet, so it's not so easy to rewatch.

Comment: How are fathiers raced? *Very carefully.*

Comment: Am I the only one that initially read this question as "How are fathers raised?"

Comment: Well, it was a very short scene, so there wasn't much to see. I do remember thinking, hey, it looks just like not all of them have riders. And then the scene was over.

Comment: This is your father's fathier. An elegant animal, for a more civilized race.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is answered in *The Last Jedi: Visual Dictionary*. On the page for Fathiers there are Fathier Jockeys and images of a saddle and whip. As such it appears they are raced with a rider like a horse race.

> **Fathier Jockeys**
>
> The skill of the jockeys separates prize-winners from also-rans, but it is a risky profession: falls are often fatal. Most races in Canto Bight are flat races - without jumps - meaning that raw speed is the ultimate factor in victories. Fathiers do not have the endurance to run at full speed across the entire race, so jockeys must apply force for bursts of speed when it can be most impactful.

[image: Fathiers]

This is also backed up by the databank page on [Fathier jockeys](https://www.starwars.com/databank/fathier-jockeys).

> Fathier racing is a dangerous business in which falls are often fatal. This gives Canto Bight’s fathier jockeys a reputation far larger than their size – the resort town’s best riders are celebrities in their own right. The best jockeys know how to persuade their mounts to run without striking them with an electrocrop.

Which also includes an image which I believe is from the final cut of the film showing a jockey racing a Fathier.

[image: Fathier jockey]

Answer (score 25):

When Finn and Rose dismount from their fathier and release it, we see them remove the saddle that they’ve been using to ride it. The existence of such saddles implies that they are ridden like horses when being raced.

Comment: I wasn't going to answer from the film since I couldn't remember exactly but I believe there's a jockey fighting a fathier in the pens and a race with jockeys going on when Finn looks through the scope.

Answer (score 14):

Other than looking like a sheep/horse hybrid, and being much larger, we see in *The Last Jedi* that they are essentially treated no differently than we treat horses. The canon book [Star Wars Made Easy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Made_Easy:_A_Beginner%27s_Guide_to_a_Galaxy_Far,_Far_Away) literally calls them "space horses"

> **SPACE HORSES**
>
> Graceful and majestic creatures, fathiers are prized across the galaxy
> for their ability to run extremely fast. The Canto Bight casinos
> exploit them for competitive (and highly popular) races
>
> [image]

Here's a behind-the-scenes of Finn and Rose riding one (apparently they constructed a full-size model for the scene). This is how we see all the fathier jockeys riding them as well

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Fathiers have jockeys. We directly observe this when a character looks through a scope, as has been noted in the comments.
They are raced around what appears to be an oval track, exactly like a horse racing track on Earth.
The manner in which they are ridden is brutal, making use of an electrified* crop that leaves deep, permanent physical scars. Various other electrified prods  are used during their handling outside the race itself, explaining the scars that are not from a crop, in areas like the face.

*When I say electrified, I'm describing how it looks, not its in universe technical definition (plasma-boson vibranium?)

Comment: Neutron-fluctuated unobtanium. With a shaft-passer on the crop.